# Titles beginning with double-quotes are missing their first and last characters in Stack Exchange global profiles

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, network-profile

In the "Top Questions" and "Top Answers" listings on Stack Exchange global profiles, the last and first characters are missing from any titles that start with a double-quote character.

I noticed this happening to [a "Top Question" in my global profile on StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/users/851/jeremy-banks):

```
 original title: "Abusing" bounties for unlimited profit
displayed title: Abusing" bounties for unlimited profi
```

As a test, I prepended a double-quote character to the title of another one of my other top posts. The same thing happened to it.

I found the same thing happening to the title of a "Top Answer" in [another user's profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/141090/mad-scientist):

```
 original title: "[open]" + "[source]" versus "[open-source]"
displayed title: [open]“ + ”[source]“ versus ”[open-source]
```

This affects the URL slugs as well as the displayed titles.

Comment: Seems like [this bug](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/issues/99)... I'll bug Demis when he gets into the office tomorrow.

Comment: @emmett still an issue? getting flags on this, as frequently as yesterday

Comment: @Emmett This seems to be fixed for questions but not for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demis was kind enough to quickly push a [ServiceStack fix](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/7fcc505e287f4736b48857d642fadcfb488cd568) so this is working correctly again. Thanks for the report.

Comment: Is the fix live? I just saw the issue again today and accidentally posted [another bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135725/156562).

Comment: @Cory Ah yeah, we need to pull the fix into the core SO codebase as well. Thanks for the heads up.