# Hot Questions clips quotes wrongly in questions like '"this" and "that"'

Tags: bug, status-completed, hot-questions, stack-exchange-button

The Hot Questions in the StackEchange dropdown display questions like

> "This" and "that"

as

> This" and "that

Example:

[image: Stack Exchange button "Hot Questions" list with broken title]

[Example 2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/31849):

[image: Stack Exchange button "Hot Questions" list with broken title]

Comment: Same thing as http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134320/160410

Comment: Thanks @DavidFullertion for the free-hand circle goodness! And Tim Stone for cleaning up David's changes :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was a bug in our JSON deserialization code.

We recently pulled in [the fix](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/7fcc505e287f4736b48857d642fadcfb488cd568) as part of the latest version of the [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text), so it shouldn't happen any more.

**EDIT**

It's still happening. The ServiceStack fix didn't actually fix it. Stay tuned.

**EDIT 2**

We just deployed with ServiceStack.Text 3.9.3, and I confirmed that the bug is actually fixed this time.

Comment: This is happening again, see Tim Cooper's edit to OP.

Comment: can you confirm the fix is live?

Comment: The "fix" is live, but it didn't actually fix the problem. Sorry about that. Bugging Demis again..