# Question titles wrapped in quotations in the "Hot Questions" part of the notification bar are displaying incorrectly

Tags: bug, notifications, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hot Questions clips quotes wrongly in questions like '“this” and “that”'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135588/hot-questions-clips-quotes-wrongly-in-questions-like-this-and-that)

I saw an odd-looking question title in the "Hot Questions" section of the StackExchange bar and took a closer look. It seems that the first and last double-quote characters are missing from the question title when displayed in the "Hot Questions" list (for titles that are indeed wrapped with double-quotation marks).

In this case, it's the `Negative" versus "Minus` entry. Take a gander:

[image]

When [visiting the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157127/negative-versus-minus), it's clearly not the way the title was entered:

[image]

Comment: Oops. And I tried searching, too. Here's a more active post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134320/156562