# StackExchange Dropdown strips quotes when it shouldn't

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Titles beginning with double-quotes are missing their first and last characters in Stack Exchange global profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134320/titles-beginning-with-double-quotes-are-missing-their-first-and-last-characters)
>   [Hot Questions clips quotes wrongly in questions like '“this” and “that”'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135588/hot-questions-clips-quotes-wrongly-in-questions-like-this-and-that)

The Stack Exchange dropdown seems to mangle questions that begin and end with a quote mark.

[image]

Compare to the actual title of the question.

[image]

I imagine this formatting occurs because, for most questions that are surrounded by quotes, removing them doesn't change the meaning of the title. `"Maximum recursion depth exceeded"` and `Maximum recursion depth exceeded` are both equally valid. But `"X" vs. "Y"` is more valid than `X" vs. "Y`.

Perhaps the dropdown should only strip quotes if the beginning and ending characters are the only quote marks in the title?