# Leading and trailing double quotes in hot question titles fail to appear

Tags: bug, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Titles beginning with double-quotes are missing their first and last characters in Stack Exchange global profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134320/titles-beginning-with-double-quotes-are-missing-their-first-and-last-characters)
>   [Hot Questions clips quotes wrongly in questions like '“this” and “that”'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135588/hot-questions-clips-quotes-wrongly-in-questions-like-this-and-that)

In the “hot questions” listing, the title for ["I am on it" vs. "I am at it"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74510/i-am-on-it-vs-i-am-at-it) appears as:

> I am on it" vs. "I am at it

I.e., without the initial or final double-quote characters. It seems related to [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134320/titles-beginning-with-double-quotes-are-missing-their-first-and-last-characters) which has reportedly been fixed. The effect is present on any SE site.

Comment: @John: I linked that, but I could certainly be wrong. It’s about profiles, which this isn’t, and marked as resolved, which, if this is a dupe, it isn’t.

Comment: (I'm voting to close as duplicate on the basis that the [meta-tag:status-completed] on the other question is actually invalid, since the comments on Emmett's answer suggest the purported fix never actually happened)

Comment: @TimStone: Okay. I just flagged the other with a link to this one.

Comment: I see the proper `“I am on it” vs. “I am at it”`